# Alternative to eval()

Tags: ruby, security, eval

I'm looking for an alternative to that code:

```
 expl = eval "BeEF::Modules::Exploits::#{klass.capitalize}.new"
```

Here the eval is totally insecure. Is there an alternative I could use to generate dynamically classes without using eval? As in, klass is always different. So my code stays generic.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Module#const_get:

```
expl = BeEF::Modules::Exploits.const_get(klass.capitalize).new
```